# Object is not clickable when it is a child of another object in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, i made a simple code in unity that outputs "clicked" when the object is clicked by using this simple code :

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
     Debug.Log("clicked");
}
```

it displays the message when clicked, but when the same object is a child of another object it is not clickable and doesn't display the message.

How do i make it clickable when it is a child ?

Answer (score 0):

You should always be aware of the colliders of parented objects. When the collider of your child object is within the collider of the parent object the OnMouseDown trigger will only hit the first collider it (well) collides with. 
You need the collider of the child object to be reachable. 
You can deativate the collider of the parent object.
You can scale the collider of the child object up.
Or you write your own method, which only checks colliders with a given tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a Rigidbody to the parent object (probably in your case you also need to set "Is Kinematic" to true) and make sure child objects have colliders.